# How to fix Segmentation Fault error when instantiating objects

Tags: c++, class

I'm working to create a few classes that work together to simulate functions for a rental car agency. I have the classes working and I can create objects of each of the classes, but when I try to run the following code I get a segmentation fault and I'm not sure why. Why am I getting a segmentation fault when I declare the objects in this order?

I've tried switching the order in which I declare the objects and the error goes away. If I declare two cars with just the `Car()` constructor, then the problem also goes away. If I remove any of the functions in either the Car or Sensor class, the error goes away.

PS: I asked this question a few days ago, and I included way too much code because I couldn't identify the error (far from complete, minimal, and verifiable), but this time I've narrowed it down as far as I can. I apologize if it's a lot of code, but I've removed all the code I can and if I remove any more of it the problem goes away.

Here's my main file:

```
#include "Car.h"

int main() {
    char make[] = "Subaru", model[] = "Outback", name[] = "Brandon", 
type[] = "radar";
    Sensor sensors[3];
    Sensor sensor1 = Sensor(type), sensor2 = Sensor(), sensor3 = 
           Sensor();
    sensors[0] = sensor1;
    sensors[1] = sensor2;
    sensors[2]= sensor3;
    Car car1 = Car();
    Car car2 = Car(make, 155.81, sensors);

    return 0;
}
```

My Car class:

```
#ifndef CAR_H
#define CAR_H

#include <iostream>
#include "MyString.h"
#include "Sensor.h"
using namespace std;

#define MAX_STR_SIZE 256
#define MAX_NUM_SNSRS 3

class Car {
    public:
     Car();
     Car(char* make, float baseprice, Sensor* sensors);
     void setMake(char* make);
     void setBaseprice(float baseprice);
     void setAvailable(bool available);
     void setOwner(char* owner);
     void updatePrice();
    private:
     char m_make[MAX_STR_SIZE];
     Sensor m_sensors[MAX_NUM_SNSRS];
     int m_numsensors;
     float m_baseprice;
     float m_finalprice;
     bool m_available;
     char m_owner[MAX_STR_SIZE];
};

#endif

#include "Car.h"

Car::Car() {
    char dflt[] = {'\0'};
    setMake(dflt);
    setAvailable(true);
    setOwner(dflt);
    m_numsensors = 0;
    setBaseprice(0.0);
}

Car::Car(char* make, float baseprice, Sensor* sensors) {
    char dflt[] = {'\0'};
    setMake(make);
    setAvailable(true);
    setOwner(dflt);
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_NUM_SNSRS; i++) {
        (*(m_sensors + i)) = Sensor(*(sensors + i));
        if(myStringCompare((sensors + i)->getType(), "none") != 0) {
            m_numsensors++;
        }
    }
    setBaseprice(baseprice);
}

void Car::setMake(char* make) {
    myStringCopy(m_make, make);
}

void Car::setBaseprice(float baseprice) {
    m_baseprice = baseprice;
    updatePrice();
}

void Car::setAvailable(bool available) {
    m_available = available;
}

void Car::setOwner(char* owner) {
    myStringCopy(m_owner, owner);
}

void Car::updatePrice() {
    float totSnsrPrice = 0.0;
    for(int i = 0; i < m_numsensors; i++) {
        totSnsrPrice += (m_sensors + i)->getCost();
    }
    m_finalprice = m_baseprice + totSnsrPrice;
}
```

My Sensor class:

```
#ifndef SENSOR_H
#define SENSOR_H

#include "MyString.h"

#define MAX_STR_SIZE 256
#define NUM_TYPES 5

class Sensor {
    public:
     Sensor();
     Sensor(char* type);
     char* getType();
     float getCost();
     void setType(char* type);
     void setCost(float extraCost);
    private:
     char m_type[MAX_STR_SIZE];
     float m_extracost;
};

#endif

#include "Sensor.h"

const char* validSensors[] = {"gps", "camera", "lidar", "radar", 
                              "none"};
const float prices[] = {5.0, 10.0, 15.0, 20.0, 0.0};

Sensor::Sensor() {
    char dflt[] = "none";
    setType(dflt);
    setCost(0.0);
}

Sensor::Sensor(char* type) {
    int index = -1;
    char dflt[] = "none";
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_TYPES; i++) {
        if(myStringCompare(type, *(validSensors + i)) == 0) {
            index = i;
        }
    }
    if(index < 0) {
        setType(dflt);
        setCost(0.0);
    } else {
        setType(type);
        setCost(*(prices + index));
    }
}

char* Sensor::getType() {
    return m_type;
}

float Sensor::getCost() {
    return m_extracost;
}

void Sensor::setType(char* type) {
    myStringCopy(m_type, type);
}

void Sensor::setCost(float extracost) {
    m_extracost = extracost;
}
```

myStringCopy and myStringCompare are just the typical std::string copy and compare functions, we're just not allowed to use them (they are include in MyString.h, I've been using them for a while, so I know they work as intended).

I expect the output to be nothing, but still successful, instead of a segmentation fault. I cannot find the error anywhere, any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: Here's my string class, as asked:

```
#ifndef MYSTRING_H
#define MYSTRING_H

int myStringCompare(const char* str1, const char* str2);

char* myStringCopy(char* destination, const char* source);

#endif

#include "MyString.h"

int myStringCompare(const char* str1, const char* str2) {
    int index = 0;
    while(*(str1 + index) != '\0' || *(str2 + index) != '\0') {
        if(*(str1 + index) < *(str2 + index)) {
            return -1;
        }

        if(*(str1 + index) > *(str2 + index)) {
            return 1;
        }
        index++;
    }
    return 0;
}

char* myStringCopy(char* destination, const char* source) {
    int index = 0;
    while(*(source + index) != '\0') {
        *(destination + index) = *(source + index);
        index++;
    }
    *(destination + index) = '\0';
    return destination;
}
```

Comment: Use your debugger, it will show you exactly where the fatal error is.

Comment: You should at least modify your code so we can run it. You say that the `MyString.h` stuff works as intended, that's great, but we still can't run the application without it. Also, if you're just getting a segmentation fault, then perhaps you should debug the program properly. Make a C++ project in a proper IDE, past the code in there and run it. It will mark the line at which the program crashes.

Comment: "I've been using them for a while, so I know they work as intended" is not a valid conclusion. Bugs can go undetected for years.

Comment: Does your setup tell you what line the problem happens on? BTW, why are you using a `char *` if you are sure your `MyString` works ok? What happens when you call `sensors[0] = sensor1;`?

Comment: Also, as a tip, having multiple files goes a bit against the "minimal" in "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example". It's no fun pasting together multiple files, finding and removing the include guards just to find that it doesn't compile because a bunch of functions are missing.

Comment: @Blaze Yeah, I tried to put it all in one file, but then the error stopped running, so I figured the file separation might have something to do with it. But thanks for the advice!

Comment: @doctorlove We're required to use pointers everywhere - no square brackets except when declaring a string. When I call `sensors[0] = sensor1;` aren't I just assigning the first element of the array to be the sensor1 variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have the full details on your string class, so this is hard to reproduce.

However, when you call `sensors[0] = sensor1;` you are copying your `Sensor`, but haven't defined an assignment operator (or copy constructor for that matter).

You also do this in the `Car` constructor with

```
(*(m_sensors + i)) = Sensor(*(sensors + i));
```

Now without the full details of your string class, I can give suggestions that might help.

First, you are doing a lot of copying when you set up the senors.

You can collapse this

```
Sensor sensors[3];
Sensor sensor1 = Sensor(type), sensor2 = Sensor(), sensor3 = 
       Sensor();
sensors[0] = sensor1;
sensors[1] = sensor2;
sensors[2]= sensor3;
```

down to

```
    Sensor sensors[3]={{type}, {}, {}};
```

This might not solve the problem, but is less to look at.

Next, remove the setters. You can use delegating constructors to tie the two you have together, and avoid these. 
This avoids some copies.

Look very carefully at what gets deep or shallow copied.

If you have two `char *` types,

```
char * word = "Hello";
char * another_word = word;
```

the second is a "shallow" copy. You need an equivalent of `strcpy` to actually make a different ("deep") copy of the string.

Comment: A few things: We're required to have setter commands, but I see what you mean about the constructors I think. I did write a copy constructor for sensors and car, but removing it seemed to not affect the error so I didn't include them. I'm not sure what you mean by being deep or shallow copied. Collapsing that does look a little better, although it didn't solve the problem - for reference, my main file is just to test this error, so that's why I just wrote the code like that.

Comment: I've explained deep v shallow - hopefully.

Comment: Yeah, I think that makes sense- I'll look again and keep that in mind. Thank you so much for your help!